# How to keep viewModel state when fragment is destroyed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have an issue with keeping the state of data in a viewModel. The viewModel that I have is initialised inside of the `onViewCreated` method like this:

```
val viewModel: PlayerViewModelImpl by viewModels {
            ViewModelFactory(
              PlayerRepositoryImpl(MockContentProviderImpl()),
              ClipsAudioPlayerImpl.getInstance(requireActivity()),
              storage
            )
          }
```

and whenever i go back, and then open the fragment again I lose all the data that was processed inside of the viewModel. Does anyone have an idea on how can I retain the data and state of the viewModel for this scenario?
Also here is my ViewModelFactory class:

```
/**
 * Factory for view models.
 */
class ViewModelFactory(
  private val repository: PlayerRepository,
  private val player: ClipsAudioPlayer<ClipsModel>,
  private val storage: PreferencesStorage): ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

  override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>, extras: CreationExtras): T = PlayerViewModelImpl(repository,storage,player) as T
}
```

Any help will be very much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the scope of the `ViewModel` to a `context` greater than the `Fragments`.

```
val factory = ViewModelFactory(
    PlayerRepositoryImpl(MockContentProviderImpl()),
    ClipsAudioPlayerImpl.getInstance(requireActivity()),
    storage
)
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(),factory).get(PlayerViewModelImpl::class.java)
```

As long as the current activity isn't destroyed the `ViewModel` should be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SharedViewModel** concept to resolve this problem. You can keep the ViewModel alive if it attached to activity.

From its name, **SharedViewModel** can share data between fragments, or activities.

What you are going to do is to:

Use **activityViewModel** delegate

Follow the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) you will find a proper example that solve your problem.